# Pyspark Sql: fail to run query on Kerberized Cluster. Permission denied

Tags: apache-spark, authentication, apache-spark-sql, kerberos

I run the following pyspark code:

MySpark.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sconf = SparkConf().setAppName('test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=sconf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df1 = sqlContext.sql("show databases")
df1.show()

df2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from mydb.mytable")
df2.show()
```

I run MySpark using the following command:

```sh
spark-submit MySpark.py --keytab myuser.keytab --principal myuser@MYDOMAIN.COM --spark.ssl.enabled=true
```

df1.show() is executed normally.
But df2.show() returns the following exception:

```py
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/mytable":hive:hive:drwxrwx--x
```

First i thought that "myuser" does not have rights to read the database "mydb". But then i used beeline and i was able to run a query:

```py
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://name.domain.com:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@MYDOMAIN.COM;ssl=true"

Beeline version 2.1.1-cdh6.3.4 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://name.domain.com:1000> select * from mydb.mytable;
```

The 'select' is executed as expected. So 'myuser' seems to have the rights to read the db.
Am i missing something regarding kerberos authentication?

Comment: What is the Hive security model? I.e. does Hive check your "application-level" privileges then access HDFS with its own `hive` user? Or does it use _your_ user account to access HDFS, like Spark does?

Comment: Given the error message you get, it's easy to guess the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark doesn't honour any kind of authentication. It will depend on hdfs authentication. So please check in Ranger do you have proper hdfs permission and hive database/table permission.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. My user didn't had permissions to read from this DB in HDFS.